# How to debug kernel written in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, operating-system, kernel

I am developing my kernel in C++.

So can any one please explain me step by step

How to debug a kernel?

I am using `Linux OS` and `GCC` and `NASM` for building my kernel.

Ans for testing kernel i am using `genisoimage` and `virtualbox 4.x`

Help Me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) as an emulator, it comes with some debugging capabilities.

Comment: Is it available for Linux Fedora Core 15?

Comment: It's built for Linux, I know it runs on Ubuntu so I don't see why it shouldn't work on Ferdora. The source if there if needs be anyway.

Comment: OK, i am downloading now a tar file.They also provide a rpm file for fedora, i know how to install from RPM source file, but i don't know how to enable debugging support while installing from RPM file.Installing from RPM is easier than from TAR file.Can you help.

Comment: Sorry, I know less than you about this. I just remember that when I was osdeving I found bochs very useful (I installed the Ubuntu package, nice and simple :p)

Comment: It is going to hard to understand `bochs` for me.How to boot `ISO` image from `BOCHS`?

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/bochs-for-linux). You need to change the .bochsrc file, there will be documentation somewhere.